# Checking if an invite is permanent Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm creating a bot for an advertising server and I want to be able to detect permanent and non-permanent invites. (As in the invite will never expire)
I've tried to check the length of the invite and from there determining if it's permanent or not. But it's probably more complicated than that since it didn't work on all of the invites.

I've only been programming for a few months so I'm sorry if this is a really dumb question. ;-;

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't show your code I cannot answer in more details.

Only general advice: read documentation carefully.

[discord.Invite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Invite) object has a [max_age](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Invite.max_age) attribute.

> How long the before the invite expires in seconds. A value of 0 indicates that it doesn’t expire.

Looks like the thing you need.

Comment: When I print `invite.max_age` it says `None`. Is it possible to get this attribute using `client.fetch_invite`?

Comment: Documentation says, that depending on the way you get `Invite` instances, some attributes can be `None`. May be `fetch_invite` cannot fill this attribute. I just googled `"discord py invite max_age none"`. https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1625 may be this can help? Or other link from search results?